# Magento 2.3.x: Data Migration - product show out of stock after migration

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4

After migration all product showing out of stock

Comment: what is the issue here? what you are trying to do?

Comment: The issue that after migration all product show out of stock even it has been assigned stock quantity . so after running  this query your out of stock issue will be finshed

Comment: so is any issue here? I think u resolved it by yourself, what is the question here?Are you seeking for any help?

Comment: yes i have solved this error and shared my solution  here hope this solution will help someone

Comment: That's good!!, Great to hear you resolved it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try backup the `inventory_source_item` table and use the below query:

```
    insert into `inventory_source_item`
    (source_code, sku, quantity, status)
    select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)))
```

Please take backup before running this query in your Database.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Vikas, it really helped. And worked in Magento 2.4 :)

Comment: Hello, I tried this SQL but I got error #1062 - 'default-757614000000'  'INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_SKU' - duplicate entry

Comment: @GustavoUlyssea You need to truncate table `inventoty_source_item` and then run the query.

Comment: Hello, I have same issue, I tried above sql, did reindex but still same all the products are showing out of stock.

Comment: @DavidCoder did you truncate the table

Comment: Yes I truncate table and run above query

Comment: I get this error    #1062 - Duplicate entry 'default-' for key 'INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_SKU'

Comment: I change the query to and it worked "insert into `inventory_source_item` (source_code, sku, quantity, status) select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`))) WHERE sku !='';"

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you really helped us with this.
Had same problem, we were searching all day and this helped a lot.

Our problem was that Amasty Custom stock status was not always showing the correct custom stock status rules. So sometimes it did, sometimes not.
So if things were in stock it said out of stock, and for products out of stock it showed in stock.

We had to truncate the table first and ran the query.

Thanks for sharing, hope other will help.

It was after a migration from magento 1 to magento 2.

So hope this will help others !!!